# Running vitest on compiled javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vitest

Trying to figure out how to run vitest on compiled javascript. Right now I'm getting a bunch of errors that look like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spyOn')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mock')
etc...
```

Which are being thrown by references to vi in my code, eg in index.test.ts:

```
import { vi, it, describe, beforeAll, expect, afterEach } from 'vitest'
vi.mock('some module')
```

Here is the relevant compilerOptions from the tsconfig in the module:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "es2015",
      "dom"
  ],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es2020",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "incremental": true,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "types": [
    "vitest/globals"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Not even sure if this is possible! I'm new to typescript!

Best

Comment: Please follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you check logging the `vi` object if it's being properly loaded in your runtime environment `console.log(vi)`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your are not importing 'some module' when calling vi.mock.
Based on your config file i guess you need to add an import to that module.

Try adding an import as follows:

```
import { commonjs } from '{Path}'
```

Comment: That's a good shout but I think something else going on. vitest itself not getting compiled/imported correctly. For example `TypeError: (0 , vitest_1.describe) is not a function`

Comment: vitest has not global variables declared you need to import them explicitly, try this: npm i vitest -D The describe type error should dissapear/change. let me know.

Comment: That didn't do it unfortunately